# How do I restore the "Quick Start" migration from my iPhone X to a newly bought iPhone 11 Pro Max?

Tags: iphone, ios, migration

I just bought a new iPhone 11 pro max.

After turning it on and did some very simple settings, it asks me to transfer data from my previous iPhone.

However, I accidentally switched to another app on the previous iPhone. After switching back to the home screen, the popup about transferring data was gone. I could never manage to restart the "Quick Start" feature.

How can I restart the "Quick Start" feature so that I can complete transferring apps from the old phone to my new phone?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can’t resume an interrupted Quick Start. You can start again by erasing your new phone (Settings → General → Reset → Erase All Content and Settings) which will start the phone back at Setup, where you can begin Quick Start again.

Answer (score 1):

Same thing happened to me. Just restart your old device and the popup should come up again.